# Colspan and rowspan working in some places not in all places

Tags: html, html-table

I have the following html code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th> a block</th>
<th>b block</th>
<th> c block</th>
<td colspan=2>d block</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>e block</td>
<td>f block</td>
<td rowspan=2>g block</td>
<td rowspan=2>h block</td>
<td rowspan=2>i block</td>
<td colspan=2>j block</td>
</tr>
<tr><td> s block</td>
<th> welcome</th>
<td colspan=2>k block</td>
<td rowspan=2>l block</td>
<td colspan=2>m block</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I know this code is quite crazy. But this has been asked in my examination to write its output. There are alternatives to colspan and rowspan in CSS yet what shall I do, its my examination. When I ran this code in Edge, I got the output [image: as this] I got the same output while using chrome too.

My doubt is `colspan` attribute is applied in `d block` but not in `j block`, `k block` and `m block`. Why is that happening? Why colspan attribute is applied to a certain cell not all? Similar question for rowspan too. rowspan not applied to `l block`?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have any photo of the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`j block` and `k block` are both 2 columns wide, but the right column is 0px wide. Same for `l block`: the lower row is 0px tall.

Add 3 more cells with stuff in them to the first row and you'll see that j/k blocks stretch across 2 columns.

Also, Edge and Chrome use the same rendering engine so the output will look the same in them, no matter if it's right or wrong. Use Firefox or Safari if you want to see a different engine's output.